# Test tightly coupled classes in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have this original code:

```
public SomeClass(int parameter) {
        this.someProperty = parameter;
        this.apiObject = new SomeApiClass(someProperty);
        for(i=0; i < 2; i++)
            apiObject.setApiProperty(i, "Hello World");
    }
```

The code works perfectly fine. But the problem arises when I try to test the same.

```
    @Mock
    private SomeApiClass someApiClass;

    private SomeClass someClass;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        someClass = new SomeClass(3);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateSomeClass() {
        verify(someApiClass, times(2)). setApiProperty(anyInt(),anyString());
    }
```

I understand why this test wouldn't pass. This would work if I change the constructor to this:

```
public SomeClass(int parameter, SomeApiClass someApiClass) {
    ...
}
```

How do I test the original code if I do not want to inject `SomeApiClass` to the constructor and also can't afford to provide any getters in it.

PS: Please ignore typos in the code. Typed it on the fly.

Comment: SomeClass probably provides a way to access its own state (including the state of the SomeApiClass that it owns). Test that this state is correct after you've called the constructor. Hard to help more with only the partial code you provided.

Comment: @JBNizet  what if I don't want to provide getters for the state.(if that's what you meant by it). I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: If you don't have getters for the state, and this state isn't used to to anything, then this state is useless, and you should remove it. So, either call the getters to know if the state is correct, or call the method that does something with that state, and see if, based on the state, the correct thing is done.

Comment: @JBNizet But how would I test whether `setApiProperty` is being called? That is the main priority.

Comment: You can't test that. Not with that design.

Comment: @JBNizet can you then suggest how should I change it? Other than injecting the other class as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I already did that. Let's take an example. To test that a car has wheels allowing it to drive, there are three ways. 1: the way you're trying to use: check if Peter, who works on the car assembly line, has put 4 wheels on the car (i.e. test if the constructor of the car did the right thing). 2. One of the ways I suggest: look at the car, and see if it indeed has 4 wheels (i.e. inspect the state of the car). 3. The second way I suggest: drive the car, and see if everything works as expected (i.e. use the car, and check it behaves as expected).

Comment: You would probably have to look at using powermockito. Design wise your code is poorly designed as it relates to testability. It is very limited how you can provide that class with a mock/stub of its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet! that was helpful

Answer (score 2):

It's good to think about testability when you design your class and also to differentiate parameters and dependencies.

Dependencies are objects that the class will rely on to get its work done. They generally don't change throughout the lifecycle of the dependee object.

Parameters are more localized than dependencies. They are expected to change in between calls to the methods of the object.

In the original code, it looks like the work done in the constructor for `SomeClass` should really go inside a method:

```
public class SomeClass {


    public void doWork(int parameter) {
        //
    }

}
```

Inside the method, if you are only interested in instantiating `SomeApiObject` with the parameter, then why not follow the Law of Demeter and pass in directly `SomeApiObject` as a parameter:

```
public void doWork(SomeApiObject someApiObject) {
    //
}
```

Then the consumer does the work:

```
someClass.doWork(new SomeApiObject(3));
```

and it can be tested by passing in a mocked `SomeApiObject` as a parameter:

```
//act
someClass.doWork(mockedSomeApiObject);

//assert
verify(mockedSomeApiObject).someVerification();
```

However, if you want a combination of parameters and dependencies you can use a Factory as a dependency:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private final SomeApiObjectFactory someApiObjectFactory;

    public SomeClass(SomeApiObjectFactory someApiObjectFactory) {
        this.someApiObjectFactory = someApiObjectFactory;
    }

    public void doWork(int parameter) {
         SomeApiObject someApiObject = someApiObjectFactory.create(parameter);
         //etc
    }
```

Then you can now test the class since you have a way to supply mocks on which behaviour can be verified:

```
SomeApiObject mockSomeApiObject = Mockito.mock(SomeApiObject.class); 
when(mockSomeApiObjectFactory.create(anyInt()).thenReturn(mockApiObject);
```

Aside from all of that there are ways of using Powermockito to test your original class as it is without alteration but these are not ideal and it is best to refactor if possible so you can use plain Mockito to test. This will give you good OO habits. Good luck!

Comment: I had thought about this, but the problem is that I can't have the `doWork()` as a public method in the class. Maybe as @JBNizet suggested, I should go check if the functionality is working rather than testing this stuff. Thanks @David